# Date string error

Tags: ruby, string, date

When I try to add my date via IRB in terminal:

```
song.released_on = Date.new(2013,10,10)
```

it says there is following error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Date into String`

in this code:

```
def released_on=date
  super Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

I've tried for several hours know and cant find the issue. Was wondering someone could help out?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code:

```
def released_on=date
  super Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
end
```

Uses the `strptime` (string-parse-time) function of the Date class. It expects two strings, one representing the actual date, and one with a string formatter.

All you need to do in order to get things working is to change:

```
song.released_on = Date.new(2013,10,10) # Wrong, not a string!
song.released_on = '10/10/2013' # Correct!
```

You could also change the function to also accept a date:

```
def released_on=date
  parsed_date = case date
    when String then Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')
    when Date then date
    else raise "Unable to parse date, must be Date or String of format '%m/%d/%Y'"
  end
  super parsed_date
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass a `Date` instance to [`Date::strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime):

```
date = Date.new(2013,10,10)
Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')  #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Date into String
```

Instead you have to pass a `String` (using the correct format):

```
date = "10/10/2013"
Date.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')  #=> Thu, 10 Oct 2013
```

Comment: Or make `released_on=` smart enough to pass a `Date` through as-is.